# Is there a way to send files AS-IS via Fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to use using [`Fluentd`](http://www.fluentd.org/) to aggregate log files from various servers. And by default it parses the log lines in various ways (and I can see the value in doing that) but in my current situation I would like to send the files **AS-IS**, without parsing and without changing a thing.

I'm using the [`in_tail`](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail) plugin with the following configurations:

```
<source>
  type tail
  format none
  read_from_head true
  path /path/to/logs/*.log
  pos_file /path/to/logs/pos_file
  tag mylog
</source>
```

And even this `none` format parses the logs. For example

`I am a line of log`

gets parsed as

`{"message":"hello world. I am a line of log!"}`

I guess the question is: Is there a way for it to send the tail content, without altering anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, all messages in fluentd will be handled as JSON objects but what you could do is on the receiving end match with a file output (`out_file`) and that would basically just create log files on the receiving end with the same content as the source.

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_file

You could even "hack" it to output with the format csv and set the delimiter to a whitespace. That could also work...